# What happened to wso2 application server url mapping feature?

Tags: wso2

We are presently using WSO2 application server version 5.0.1 and rely on its web application url mapping feature to map our single web application to various client url's. e.g. an application running on http://mydomain.com:9763/example/ can be mapped to http://client1.mydomain.com:9763/ as well as http://client2.mydomain.com:9763/

In the new version 5.2.1 of WSO2 application server, I cant find the url mapping feature anywhere. I added the http://dist.wso2.org/p2/carbon/releases/4.2.0/features/ P2 repo and tried to search for the feature but is seems to be missing.

Has the feature been dropped? Is there a way we can have the same functionality on 5.2.1?

Answer (score 0):

Yes we have removed URL mapping feature from WSO2 appserver

Comment: Is there a workaround so that we can have the same functionality on 5.2.1?